# Como extrair e compactar arquivos com System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive em c#?

Tags: c#, arquivo-zip, compressão

Eu estou iniciando no C#. Vi que tem a classe `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` para trabalhar com arquivos zip.

Tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Como faço para descompactar um zip existente através do ZipArchive?
- Como faço pra compactar para um arquivo zip existente? Ou seja, adicionar arquivos num ZIP existente.
- Como criar um novo arquivo ZIP (do zero)? Por exemplo, quero criar um arquivo ZIP novo através do C# e adicionar arquivos existentes neste ZIP.

Comment: Se a galera do downvote tiver algum esclarecimento, será bem-vindo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nos dois primeiros casos você precisa atentar que é necessário "abrir" o arquivo zip e **sempre** é necessário liberar os recursos usando o **`Dispose()`** (o `using` chama o método automaticamente).

#### Descompactar um zip existente

Use o método [**`ExtractToDirectory()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory(v=vs.110).aspx). Passe como parâmetro o caminho que você onde você pretende descompactar os arquivos. Todos as entradas do arquivo zip serão descompactadas neste diretório.

```
string caminhoZip = @"C:\Users\LINQ\arquivo.zip";
string pastaExtrair = @"C:\Users\LINQ\extrair-aqui";

using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(caminhoZip))
{
    zip.ExtractToDirectory(pastaExtrair);
}
```

#### Adicionar arquivos num zip existente.

Use o método [**`CreateEntryFromFile()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx). O primeiro parâmetro deve ser o caminho do arquivo que pretende adicionar e o segundo parâmetro é o nome deste arquivo dentro do zip. Note que é necessário passar `ZipArchiveMode.Update` como segundo parâmetro de `ZipFile.Open()`.

```
string caminhoZip = @"C:\Users\LINQ\arquivo.zip";        
string novo = @"C:\Users\LINQ\novo.txt";

using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(caminhoZip, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(novo, "novo.txt");            
}
```

#### Criar um novo arquivo ZIP

1. Se quiser zipar uma pasta

   Use [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx). O primeiro parâmetro é a pasta que você pretende zipar e o segundo é o caminho do novo arquivo a ser criado. Se quiseres criar um arquivo zip vazio é só criá-lo a partir de uma pasta vazia.

   ```
   string pastaParaZipar = @"C:\Users\LINQ\pasta-zip";
   string caminhoZip = @"C:\Users\LINQ\arquivo-novo.zip";    

   ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(pastaParaZipar, caminhoZip);
   ```
2. Se preferir criar um arquivo e ir adicionando itens a ele

   Use `ZipFile.Open()`, passando `ZipArchiveMode.Create` como segundo parâmetro.

   ```
   string nomeArquivo = @"C:\Users\LINQ\arquivo.zip";

   using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(nomeArquivo, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
   {
       // Adicione arquivos...
   }
   ```